# Pandas parse json column and and keep existing column into a new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
name  stats
smith {"eye_color": "brown", "height": 160, "weight": 76}
jones {"eye_color": "blue", "height": 170, "weight": 85}
will  {"eye_color": "green", "height": 180, "weight": 94}
```

I use the following code to parse the json field into a new dataframe:

```
new_df = df["stats"].apply(json.loads).apply(pd.Series)
```

This gives me `new_df`:

```
eye_color height weight
brown     160    76
blue      170    85
green     180    94
```

How can I update the code the above to add `name` to `new_df`, so that I have:

```
name  eye_color height weight
smith brown     160    76
jones blue      170    85
will  green     180    94
```

Comment: `concat` back  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
new_df=df[['name']].join(df["stats"].apply(json.loads).apply(pd.Series))
```